# Storing protobuf object locally in iOS

Tags: ios, local-storage, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using gRPC for my iOS app's server communication. gRPC uses protobuf objects for these requests. I also have to store these objects locally in certain cases, and I was wondering if there was any ORM or ORM-like library or ideal way to store protobuf objects in iOS local storage. I know libraries like Realm require your data object to inherit from RealmObject, so in order for me to store my protobuf object in Realm, I would essentially have to map each value manually. Is there a way to directly store this Protobuf object in local storage for iOS? If not I think I'll simply use Realm and have a RealmObject for each protobuf and have a constructor like initWithProtoObj and essentially map the data and do vice-versa for RealmObject to Protobuf when I need to push something to the server.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi, why not just serialize each proto message and store it as a binary blob? Then parse it back again when you want to load it.

Each proto message supports NSSecureCoding, which will do this under the hood for you.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing. I created a Realm object that had a propery that simply contained the protobuf serialized as NSData. I never answered this question though. For anyone still looking for the answer to this, this is the way to go!